# How to estimate how much resources are needed in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage

I'm new to kubernetes. So I need some help with things, which are basic stuff for most of you. I build my first cluster and added some workers (bare metal).

How do I estimate how much resources/power I need for my apps? For example I'm using 10 different nextJS / node frontend applications and three nestJS backend applications, I really don't know which server dimension I have to choose. How much CPU and memory do I need?
I know there is no exact answer for this, as you cannot know how complex each app is (although in my case they are all very simple). But I hope to get some infos from you how I can estimate or measure which resources are needed in my cluster. How do I see if I need to add another worker to the cluster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: @GregAskew It helps and I know it is better to build a scalable system, that's why I'm using k8s. But how do I know the resources are not enough? How do I get this information? Then I could add another worker...

Answer (score 1):

You can use utility command `kubectl top ( node / pod)` to get the resources metrics:

```
node          Display resource (CPU/memory) usage of nodes

pod           Display resource (CPU/memory) usage of pods
```

Also, you can deploy [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) in order to get the full metrics from your cluster.